# How to order by the result of a formula?

Tags: kibana

I have data about tests done by employees (a test is failed if a `clicked_at` field is not empty), all the employees are attached to a manager.

I would like to show the results of the tests per manager. To this, I use a Lens bar visualisation, with the data being the result of the formula

```
count(kql='not clicked_at.keyword: "" ') / count()
```

The results are correct an the result is

[image]

I would like to order the bars descending, but I cannot find a way to say *"order by the results of the formula"*. is this possible?